# Sending Email in abp io with SmtpEmailSender throwing The input is not a valid Base-64 string

Tags: abp

ive been trying for a week to get email sending to work with no luck.
my test was on sending email for password reset

appsettings.json

[image: appsettings.json]

settings provider of my app

[image]

and DomainModule of my app

[image]

ive been looking at official documentation but unfortunately for me its to vague and not detailed.

after i click on forgot password, type email and click send this error pops up

```
FormatException: The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters.
System.Convert.FromBase64CharPtr(Char* inputPtr, int inputLength)
System.Convert.FromBase64String(string s)
Volo.Abp.Security.Encryption.StringEncryptionService.Decrypt(string cipherText, string passPhrase, byte[] salt)
Volo.Abp.Settings.SettingEncryptionService.Decrypt(SettingDefinition settingDefinition, string encryptedValue)
Volo.Abp.Settings.SettingProvider.GetOrNullAsync(string name)
Volo.Abp.Emailing.EmailSenderConfiguration.GetNotEmptySettingValueAsync(string name)
Volo.Abp.Emailing.Smtp.SmtpEmailSender.BuildClientAsync()
Volo.Abp.Emailing.Smtp.SmtpEmailSender.SendEmailAsync(MailMessage mail)
Volo.Abp.Emailing.EmailSenderBase.SendAsync(MailMessage mail, bool normalize)
Volo.Abp.Emailing.EmailSenderBase.SendAsync(string to, string subject, string body, bool isBodyHtml)
Volo.Abp.Account.Emailing.AccountEmailer.SendPasswordResetLinkAsync(IdentityUser user, string resetToken, string appName, string returnUrl, string returnUrlHash)
Volo.Abp.Account.AccountAppService.SendPasswordResetCodeAsync(SendPasswordResetCodeDto input)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have to store the encrypted version of your password in the appsettings.json

simply use this snippet somewhere in your app

```
public class EmailSettingProvider : SettingDefinitionProvider
{
    private readonly ISettingEncryptionService encryptionService;

    public EmailSettingProvider(ISettingEncryptionService encryptionService)
    {
        this.encryptionService = encryptionService;
    }

    public override void Define(ISettingDefinitionContext context)
    {
        var passSetting = context.GetOrNull("Abp.Mailing.Smtp.Password");
        if(passSetting!=null)
        {
            string debug = encryptionService.Encrypt(passSetting,"1q2w3e$R");
        }
    }
}
```

set a break point and copy the value in the `debug` variable to the appsettings.json file and that's all the configuration you need.